# Model for Shimura curves

Tags: nt.number-theory

There is a list of Shimura curves (upto genus 2) in the paper https://math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/articles/shimbound-mcom-fixed-errata.pdf. My question is can I construct corresponding models for them (genus 0 curves as conics, genus 1 curves as elliptic curves and so on) somehow from the information already present in the article? If there exists a list of these models already somewhere that would be helpful too. Thanks,

Comment: Hi Rakvi, Have you tried writing directly to John Voight? He's likely to know.

Comment: Thank you Professor Silverman, I was planning to write to him eventually but I thought if I am missing something obvious then would be good to post a question here first.